# Google Sheets condition formatting: format blank cells that are in even rows

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I want to create a conditional format rule in Google Sheets such that **even cells** in a **specified range** are formatted a particular color if they are **blank**.

I attempted the following:

1. Select *Format*
2. Select *Conditional formatting...*
3. *Conditional format rules* bar appears as bar in left-hand side of window
4. Enter a specific column range in *Apply to range* field
5. Select *Custom formula is* in *Format cells if...* dropdown menu
6. Enter "=ISBLANK(ISEVEN(ROW()))" in custom field directly below *Format cells if...* dropdown
7. Enter a custom color as *Formatting style*
8. Select *Done* button

Unfortunately, the custom formatting does not appear in the specified range after creating the conditional formatting rule.

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GporE.png) for additional clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in A1:

=AND(ISBLANK(A1),ISEVEN(ROW()))